# Massachusetts Absentee Ballot: Pencil or Pen?

Tags: united-states, vote-by-mail, massachusetts

This is a pretty simple question: I have received an absentee ballot in Massachusetts and I don't know which writing utensil to use to fill it out. I found with some searching that [California wants you to use a #2 pencil](http://vote.sonoma-county.org/content.aspx?sid=1009&id=1052), but I also have heard that you should use pen to prevent tampering. It isn't specified clearly anywhere, but it seems like a very important thing to know.

Personal experience is fine, but sources would be preferred.

Comment: It doesn't specify.  I think this question is a holdover from electronic scoring of exams which had to be marked in pencil because the graphite was electrically conductive.  These are being read by people, a sharpie or crayon would probably work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no requirement.  But read the instructions that came with it closely - if they don't say anything, you're probably free to use whatever you want.

[The official Massachusetts page](https://www.sec.state.ma.us/ele/eleifv/howabs.htm) explaining how to vote absentee doesn't specify anything, and [the laws governing counting votes](http://www.mass.gov/courts/docs/lawlib/900-999cmr/950cmr53.pdf) (see 53.04(18), on page 13) specify that each absentee ballot's votes are read out by one person and marked down by a different person, which implies that anything legible will do.